# For which $a\in\Bbb R^+$ is $\{1,a, a^a, a^{a^a},...\}$ linearly independent over $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation, irrational-numbers, tetration

Can I choose a positive real number $a\in\Bbb R^+$ so that $1,a,a^a,a^{a^a},...$ are independent in the sense that no combination of *integer* coefficients will add up these numbers to zero?

More formally: Given $A_0=1$ and $A_{i+1}=a^{A_i}$. Is there an $a\in\Bbb R^+$ for which I can be sure that there is no $k\in\Bbb N^+$ and no coefficients $n_i\in\Bbb Z,i=0,1,...,k\;$ with

$$n_0A_0+n_1A_1+\cdots +n_kA_k=0\quad?$$

I believe such numbers exists, and are actually very common. I just have no clue how to prove it.

Comment: trivial for $k=1$: let a be an irrational number. So really: do you ask   this for general (fixed) $k$ or for unspecified (even infinite) $k$?

Comment: @Andreas As I said, *any* combination of coefficients. No specific $k$ assumed. But $k$ is assumed finite.

Comment: Related-ish is [Schanuel's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), which is about the dependence of $a$ and $e^a$'s relation.

Comment: Can you give an example for $a$ where you conjecture that your claim holds?

Comment: @Andreas Hm. I do not conjecture anything, but $a=\pi$ seems reasonable.

Comment: Great question. Even $a=1/2$ looks like it would work.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Maybe it's because I changed the exact question formulation recently, but $a=1/2$ will give $$1\cdot1+(-2)\cdot\frac 12=0.$$

Comment: Oh, I see. You allow $k=0$. But I think no combination for $k>0$ can be zero.

Comment: For $k=2$, take any irrational $a$ where $a^a$ is an integer, such as $1.559610469462\ldots$

Comment: @Henry Maybe I was not clear, so I edited my question. I will *not* fix a $k$, but only $a$. There should be *no* vanishing linear combination for any $k$. Moreover I am not interested in counterexamples (any rational number would be), but in examples for such $a$ that do *not* have such linear combinations. I need such a number to prove the existence of certain sub-rings of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'm more interested to know if there exists $a\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ with this property.  Unfortunately, as $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ is of Lebesgue measure $0$, @HenningMakholm's great proof won't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each *particular* linear combination,
$$n_0A_0+n_1A_1+\cdots +n_kA_k$$
is an analytic function of $a$ in $(0,\infty)$. Since it is not identically zero, the *set* of its zeroes is discrete. In particular this set (which is the $a$s that are excluded by that particular linear combination) has Lebesgue measure zero.

Since there are only countably many integer combinations, this means that the *union* of the sets they exclude *also* has measure zero.

This means that there are plenty of $a$s that are *not* excluded -- in fact **almost every** $a$ has an independent sequence of tetrations.

Comment: Amazing non-constructuve proof! Thank you! But do we already know any specific number with this property?

Comment: @M.Winter: Depends on what we take "know" to mean. I doubt we can prove this property of any nicely named number such as $\pi$ or $\gamma$ or $\frac23$. However, the core of the argument here is not _essentially_ non-constructive. Instead of speaking about Lebesgue we could also construct a nested sequence of closed intervals that avoid all the zero sets -- and this can be made completely explicit, resulting in a computable sequence of rationals that converge to a given $a$ (or, alternatively an algorithm to produce decimal digits successively).